# Problem with type of function dynamic param in typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have a method with a function param.

```
export const workFunction = (fn) => {
    let response = null;
    const exec = async (...args) => {
        response = await fn(...args);
        console.log(response);
    };
    return {
        response,
        exec,
    };
};
```

this is section of composable function of vue

in the next step i use this function like bottom.

```
// exportFunction is imported function
const createApi = workFunction(exportFunction);
createApi.exec();
```

and my problem: i can't see exportFunction type of params in createApi.exec().
tip: exportFunction is dynamic function.

Comment: Are you writing a .ts file or a .js file here?  If `workFunction` is being written in TypeScript then you need to give it typings like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbne3m).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: really thank you. This was exactly the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your typing problem can be fixed by [annotating the parameter types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) of `workFunction()`.  Since you want the output's type to depend on the type of the `fn` parameter, you'll need to make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Here's how I'd do it:

```
const workFunction = <A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => R) => {
    const exec = async (...args: A) => {
        ret.response = await fn(...args);
        console.log(ret.response);
    };
    const ret = {
        response: null as Awaited<R> | null,
        exec
    }
    return ret;
};
```

So `fn` takes a [rest parameter of generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters) `A`, and returns a value of generic type `R`.  It returns an object with an `exec` method that also accepts a rest parameter of type `A`, and a `response` property of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `Awaited<R> | null`.  It's using [the `Awaited<R>` helper type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements) to indicate that if `R` is a `Promise` type, then you're getting the resolved type of `R`'s promise, otherwise you're just getting `R`, and it could always be `null` because  someone could look at `response` before calling `exec`.

Note that I also had to fix your *implementation* problem; the original version had a [closed-over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) variable named `response` that you would reassign after awaiting `fn(...args)`.  But reassigning that variable wouldn't modify the property named `response` in the returned object.  That property would always have been `null` forever.  If you want to reassign a property you need to do it through the containing object.  So I have removed the `response` variable completely and am using just the property inside the returned object.  And that means the returned object does need to be closed over, so I gave it the name `ret`.

---

Anyway, let's test it:

```
function exportFunction(x: string) {
    return Promise.resolve(x.toUpperCase());
}
// exportFunction(x: string): Promise<string>

const createApi = workFunction(exportFunction);
/* const createApi: {
response: string | null;
exec: (x: string) => Promise<void>;
} */
```

Looks good.  `exportFunction()` is of type `(x: string) => Promise<string>`, and `createApi` is of type `{response: string | null; exec: (x: string) => Promise<void>}`.  We can make sure it behaves as desired:

```
createApi.exec("hello"); // eventually prints "HELLO"
console.log(createApi.response); // probably null

await createApi.exec("goodbye"); // eventually prints "GOODBYE"
console.log(createApi.response); // "GOODBYE"
```

This is just showing you that you need to `await` the result of `createApi.exec()` if you want to guarantee that `createApi.response` is populated. Also this:

```
createApi.exec() // error! Expected 1 arguments, but got 0
createApi.exec(123); // error! Argument of type 'number' is not 
// assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

demonstrates that the compiler will be unhappy if you don't pass in the right arguments to `createApi.exec()`, which was the original point of your question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7iATgawGIFczCgS3DAXhgB4BBGAUwA8oKwATCGAQzAE8BtAXQBoYAlAHwAKAGZgAXDGEA6Oc0QBzCFNIBKQoIEaCWgN4AoGMZihIsahWCEWENlmlyZC5ap36jJr4gpQZPiAAHcAgKG2Y4ZhxYcVl5JQg1AG5PL2MzCBAAGwoZLJBFYR8-AODICmTUmABfFK8M2GKbQzSTUpCKKTB0LKzbGFJI6Ip6YiEYAB8Ybt6eKq9LYCrqquL0RDAYYpTagz3mOwdRTGw8TdpoYQ1DKuOsXHxqYMQoDHuz4SopaEQcMEVrvM2r51psAAqIEAAWxwoX8FEyWQAbhRPjIoCAAKqBQIURAAYQOqLUlS8Ky8AHoKZQqM9XicHmBPt8oL9-mopBDobCKMQfn9FII9vUQrBgD5mLRSIEcDYECg3qdwMInkh6e9wKSTBSAFSmUWmCVSmVSFrAoIdFlsxSTaY9LJ1EyLKTMmD89maGBcmGhYhIkA4eiCR3GaowHUU4UmcUUSUUaU4GSLYQAIgAFhReiAU8kYFTKCiwFB0MxemwYIE2VAmCmABIAUQAMo2APIpqoZbK5fKFGNxhPwi3lXP5ysgABGzHHWXLMyyUeMESiYqN8ZlSaoVlTihAIHo47YFBzSTz1IoheLpZnFarNYA4i2WwARABCAE16+2RZAu3kCsI+2NRN2mHE98xTB9n3fT8F0NWMgI3LcNHzPFIUQABCGB61pKxaHoGAAEYWCUdAoToas+HHdBYB3WAAAYO1XAdkwIgAmABmEcz0QNDMNIEiyKLGAQFEGAoDYXEYAAcm6KFxzxKSYFhaYQFgA4IBwRQwCnHIxJACsFGYMjaEQYTRPEySpPdRQpJkAwVgMC4oCuJIgA)